# Failure to change Theme in Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to change the Theme to Theme.Holo, but it was crashed when I run the apps. I only made change in Manifest.xml as below, and so far there are no error message shown.

Original:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
```

Changed:

```
<style name="AppTheme_Holo" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo"></style>
```

Here is the logcat:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

logcat message seem to tell me I can only use the Theme.AppCompat, and I think this theme is coming from supporting library appcompat v7:22.

I have tried to search around the link as below from Android developer site, but seem the setting above has no difference with their suggestion

May I know why I can only use the Theme from the supporting library v7:22?
Is there something I missed to change?

[Android Developer site:Styling the Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is something more. Your activity is extending [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) or [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) and that needs a `Theme.AppCompat` theme or any descendant. You just need to change that to [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or [FragmentActivity](http://android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) from support library v4.

Comment: Thanks! it's worked. I originally thought if I have to delete the V7's support library, and I have it tried finally but still fail.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to make Theme.Holo as default setting?  when I open every new project now, the theme parent is Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, and activity extent ActionBarActivity.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using `ActionBarActivity` which uses `Theme.AppCompat.*`. Make your activity extend `android.app.Activity` to get rid of this error.

Comment: How that differ from my answer?

Comment: I guess, wrote at almost same time. So didn't notice your answer :)